# Can I prevent code in a <script> element from running again when I manipulate one of its DOM parent elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here's a simplified version of what I'd like to do.  On the page there's a section of HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="wrap-this">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('Blah.');
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

And in my own script I am doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrap-this').wrap($('<div id="new-div">'));
});
```

The problem is that when I manipulate the DOM using `wrap()`, the code within the `<div>` gets called again, and I end up getting two `alert()`s.  Is there a way I can prevent that from happening without modifying the `<div>` or the code it contains?

Comment: *"...without modifying the `<div>` or the code it contians"* If you're not willing to modify your code, then the only solution I could think of would be to overwrite the `.ready()` method, and I'm not certain that's a good idea.

Comment: The problem here is **definitely not** that the "ready" event is firing twice. The problem is that jQuery runs the script on purpose. It then removes it from the DOM anyway, I'm pretty sure - that's why it doesn't happen on subsequent ".wrap()" calls.

Comment: @Pointy You're right - I've updated the title to be more clear about what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before wrapping the `div`, you could remove all script tags from it:

```
var theDiv = $('#wrap-this');
theDiv.find('script').remove();
theDiv.wrap($('<div id="new-div"/>'));
```

Comment: If you don't want to remove the `<script>`, setting its "type" attribute to "text/plain" will also prevent it from re-running.